# Count how many this word in the file but so many of them to separate

Tags: arrays, c, automatic-ref-counting

I want to count how many of country that input in the program and show 3 at the most number on it like this

USA,USA,UK,UK,Canada,Canada,south park

and the result is `Three of countries that have most number are USA,UK,Canada` for example

but the problem is I need to create char and int for every country in the world(If you have better ideas, you can tell me too but I'm just a beginner so please explain or show the final code to me to understand it) like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char * countrylist [] = {"Laotian / Lao","Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Antigua and Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Australia"
                             ,"Austria","Austrian Empire","Azerbaijan","Baden","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Bavaria","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bolivia"
                             ,"Bosnia and Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","Brunei","Brunswick and Luneburg","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Upper Volta","Burma","Burundi","Cabo Verde"
                             ,"Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cayman Islands","Central African Republic","Central American Federation","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Comoros"
                             ,"Congo Free State","Costa Rica","Cote dIvoire","Ivory Coast","Croatia","Cuba","Cyprus","Czechia","Czechoslovakia","Democratic Republic of the Congo"
                             ,"Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Duchy of Parma","East Germany","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea"
                             ,"Estonia","Eswatini","Ethiopia","Federal Government of Germany","Fiji","Finland","France","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Grand Duchy of Tuscany"
                             ,"Greece","Grenada","Guatemala","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Hanover","Hanseatic Republics","Hawaii","Hesse","Holy See","Honduras","Hungary"
                             ,"Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kingdom of Serbia","Kingdom of Yugoslavia"
                             ,"Kiribati","Korea","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Lew Chew","Loochoo","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg"
                             ,"Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mecklenburg Schwerin","Mecklenburg Strelitz","Mexico"
                             ,"Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nassau","Nauru","Nepal","Netherlands","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger"
                             ,"Nigeria","North German Confederation","North German Union","North Macedonia","Norway","Oldenburg","Oman","Orange Free State","Pakistan","Palau","Panama","Papal States"
                             ,"Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Piedmont Sardinia","Poland","Portugal","Qatar","Republic of Genoa","Republic of Korea","South Korea","Republic of the Congo"
                             ,"Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Kitts and Nevis","Saint Lucia","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia"
                             ,"Schaumburg Lippe","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Sudan","Spain"
                             ,"Sri Lanka","Sudan","Suriname","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Texas","Thailand","Timor Leste","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad and Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey"
                             ,"Turkmenistan","Tuvalu","Two Sicilies","Uganda","Ukraine","Union of Soviet Socialist Republics","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu"
                             ,"Venezuela","Vietnam","Wurttemberg","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"
                            };

    int Afghanistan=0,Albania=0,Algeria=0,Andorra=0,Angola=0,AntiguaandBarbuda=0,Argentina=0,Armenia=0,Australia=0,Austria=0,AustrianEmpire=0,Azerbaijan=0,Baden=0,Bahamas=0,Bahrain=0,Bangladesh=0,Barbados=0,Bavaria=0,Belarus=0,Belgium=0,Belize=0,Benin=0,
                                         Dahomey=0,Bolivia=0,BosniaandHerzegovina=0,Botswana=0,Brazil=0,Brunei=0,BrunswickandLuneburg=0,Bulgaria=0,BurkinaFaso=0,UpperVolta=0,Burma=0,Burundi=0,CaboVerde=0,Cambodia=0,Cameroon=0,Canada=0,CaymanIslands=0,CentralAfricanRepublic=0,CentralAmericanFederation=0,
                                         Chad=0,Chile=0,China=0,Colombia=0,Comoros=0,CongoFreeState=0,CostaRica=0,CotedIvoire=0,IvoryCoast=0,Croatia=0,Cuba=0,Cyprus=0,Czechia=0,Czechoslovakia=0,DemocraticRepublicoftheCongo=0,Denmark=0,Djibouti=0,Dominica=0,DominicanRepublic=0,DuchyofParma=0,
                                         EastGermany=0,GermanDemocraticRepublic=0,Ecuador=0,Egypt=0,ElSalvador=0,EquatorialGuinea=0,Eritrea=0,Estonia=0,Eswatini=0,Ethiopia=0,FederalGovernmentofGermany=0,Fiji=0,Finland=0,France=0,Gabon=0,Gambia=0,Georgia=0,Germany=0,Ghana=0,GrandDuchyofTuscany=0,
                                         Greece=0,Grenada=0,Guatemala=0,Guinea=0,GuineaBissau=0,Guyana=0,Haiti=0,Hanover=0,HanseaticRepublics=0,Hawaii=0,Hesse=0,HolySee=0,Honduras=0,Hungary=0,Iceland=0,India=0,Indonesia=0,Iran=0,Iraq=0,Ireland=0,Israel=0,Italy=0,Jamaica=0,Japan=0,Jordan=0,Kazakhstan=0,Kenya=0,KingdomofSerbia=0,KingdomofYugoslavia=0,
                                         Kiribati=0,Korea=0,Kosovo=0,Kuwait=0,Kyrgyzstan=0,Laos=0,Latvia=0,Lebanon=0,Lesotho=0,LewChew=0,Loochoo=0,Liberia=0,Libya=0,Liechtenstein=0,Lithuania=0,Luxembourg=0,Madagascar=0,Malawi=0,Malaysia=0,Maldives=0,Mali=0,Malta=0,MarshallIslands=0,Mauritania=0,Mauritius=0,MecklenburgSchwerin=0,MecklenburgStrelitz=0,
                                         Mexico=0,Micronesia=0,Moldova=0,Monaco=0,Mongolia=0,Montenegro=0,Morocco=0,Mozambique=0,Namibia=0,Nassau=0,Nauru=0,Nepal=0,Netherlands=0,NewZealand=0,Nicaragua=0,Niger=0,Nigeria=0,NorthGermanConfederation=0,NorthGermanUnion=0,NorthMacedonia=0,Norway=0,Oldenburg=0,Oman=0,OrangeFreeState=0,Pakistan=0,Palau=0,
                                         Panama=0,PapalStates=0,PapuaNewGuinea=0,Paraguay=0,Peru=0,Philippines=0,PiedmontSardinia=0,Poland=0,Portugal=0,Qatar=0,RepublicofGenoa=0,RepublicofKorea=0,SouthKorea=0,RepublicoftheCongo=0,Romania=0,Russia=0,Rwanda=0,SaintKittsandNevis=0,SaintLucia=0,SaintVincentandtheGrenadines=0,Samoa=0,
                                         SanMarino=0,SaoTomeandPrincipe=0,SaudiArabia=0,SchaumburgLippe=0,Senegal=0,Serbia=0,Seychelles=0,SierraLeone=0,Singapore=0,Slovakia=0,Slovenia=0,SolomonIslands=0,Somalia=0,SouthAfrica=0,SouthSudan=0,Spain=0,SriLanka=0,Sudan=0,Suriname=0,Sweden=0,Switzerland=0,Syria=0,Tajikistan=0,Tanzania=0,Texas=0,Thailand=0,
                                             TimorLeste=0,Togo=0,Tonga=0,TrinidadandTobago=0,Tunisia=0,Turkey=0,Turkmenistan=0,Tuvalu=0,TwoSicilies=0,Uganda=0,Ukraine=0,UnionofSovietSocialistRepublics=0,UnitedArabEmirates=0,UnitedKingdom=0,Uruguay=0,Uzbekistan=0,Vanuatu=0,Venezuela=0,Vietnam=0,Wurttemberg=0,Yemen=0,Zambia=0,Zimbabwe=0;



        char * s []= {"Thailand","ab"};

        int lencountry = sizeof(countrylist)/sizeof(countrylist[0]);
        int lenprovince = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < lencountry; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<lenprovince; j++)
            {
                if(!strcmp(countrylist[i], s[j]))
                {
                    //I think I need to show do int++ here but I don't know how to do it
                    //maybe know the location of countrylist[i] and make the program know 
                    //where to add 1 to int

                }
            }
        }
}
```

but this is just what I think and try to do but my skill is not enough, If you can tell me how to do it please tell me and if you have the skills to make it done please show me how.

Thank you very much to every person that helps me.

Comment: Is this some homework where you should apply specific technics from the course?

Comment: Is the input of the country list is 'user input' (i.e. you acquire the user to input) or it's static (embedded in the program) as in `s`?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not use single variables for each country. Instead use an array.
This can be done in multiple flavors:

1. Use a VLA matching your list of names:

```c
    ...
    int lencountry = sizeof(countrylist)/sizeof(countrylist[0]);
    int countrycounts[lencountry];    // VLA cannot be initialized
    for (int i = 0; i<lencountry; i++)
    {
       countrycounts[i] = 0;
    }
```

Then you can simply increment the corresponding index in that array:

```c
    if(!strcmp(countrylist[i], s[j]))
    {
      countrycounts[i]++;
    }
```

2. Use a struct and store counter together with names.

```c
typedef struct {
  const char *name;
  int         count;
} country_t;

country_t countrylist[] = {
  { .name = "Laotian / Lao"},
  { .name = "Afghanistan"},
  { .name = "Albania"},
  ...
  { .name = "Zambia"},
  { .name = "Zimbabwe"}
};
```

The remaining fields (here: `count`) in the struct are automatically initialized to 0 if not all fields are specified.

Then you can compare like this:

```c
    if(!strcmp(countrylist[i].name, s[j]))
    {
      countrylist[i].count++;
    }
```